# Add task dependencies to Rake::TestTask

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-test

How can I declare task dependencies to a TestTask ?

In this example, 'clean_database' task should be run before integration task

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:integration) do |t|
 t.libs << "test"
 t.test_files = FileList['test/**/integration/**/test*.rb']
 t.verbose = true
end

task :clean_database => [:init] do
 #...
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rake enables redefining existing tasks, so this should be possible (add it to your existing code):

```
task :integration => :clean_database
```

Answer (score 9):

You can pass in the dependency to the TestTask initializer:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:integration => :clean_database) do |t|
 t.libs << "test"
 t.test_files = FileList['test/**/integration/**/test*.rb']
 t.verbose = true
end
```